# MVC EditorFor form data doesn't reach controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate, editorfor

We have a controller SomeController with an action method Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new SomeModel());
}
```

In the view, EditorFor is called:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Submodel)
```

Submodel contains a textfield for SomeProperty inside Ajax.BeginForm:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

When rendered, SomeProperty has the value 'x' and it's changed to 'y'. I can see in the debugger that the correct value 'y' is indeed posted, but the controller receives the old value 'x'.

The controller action the model is posted to is

```
public ActionResult Update(Submodel model)
```

matching the model received by the editor template.

If I change the Index view to RenderPartial instead of EditorFor the correct new value 'y' is posted:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("/PathToControllerViews/EditorTemplates/Submodel.cshtml", Model.Submodel)
```

I searched quite a bit and the only thing I could find with a similar scenario were suggestions to clear ModelState before returning a partial view, but there are potential downsides and it doesn't seem to address the root cause.

It's such a simple structure, so why is this happening? Why does it work with RenderPartial and not with EditorFor?

Comment: add your real model and view code please

Comment: It cannot possibly work using the partial since using a partial will not give 2 way model binding - the `EditorFor()` generate `name="Submodel.SomeProperty"` which is correct to bind to your model, and the `RenderPartial()` generates `name="SomeProperty"` which could only ever bind to the model that is `Submodel` Best guess is your POST method is not binding to the same model as the view, but you have not shown the relevant code.

Comment: I re-tested it, just to make doubly sure, and it is exactly as described above; but your comment pointed me in the right direction I think; since the form is contained in the editor template, only Submodel is posted back but with EditorFor the name genrated is generated for "Submodel.SomeProperty" which is not contained in Submodel, only in SomeModel

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. And you have not shown any real code or the controller methods, not even the main model so no one can help you with this.

Comment: that IS the exact code, only the names are changed; I invite you to actually try for yourself before being so dismissive; key for reproducing it I believe is to put ajax beginform in the editor template and only post back submodel

Comment: Try what - you have NOT shown the relevant code. If your post method is `public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)` (which it needs to be because you passed `SomeModel` to the view) and you have generated your view correctly using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods then it will bind correctly. If its not, then your code is wrong but your will not show it!

Comment: not sure what else you want to see, it's as shown; maybe this helps: 1) create Index action exactly as above; 2) create corresponding view with editorfor for submodel 3) create submodel editor template with ajax beginform for posting back submodel only, which has inside it a textboxfor for someproperty; 4) post back; this should re-create the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137143/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-devlock).

Comment: yes, sent you a message - in case anybody else looks at this, in a nutshell where I went wrong was only posting submodel from editorfor; the choices w/o introducing scripting as far as I can see are either post back the entire model each time or use renderpartial to avoid names generated in accordance with the full model

Comment: thanks for the BindPrefix tip, that fixed it; if you post as answer I'll mark it accordingly